# How to solve Gtk-WARNING about “pixmap”

Tags: themes, gtk

Whenever I start an application, for example, chrome, I am getting the following errors/warnings:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[3218:3218:1126/180808:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[3218:3218:1126/180808:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[3218:3218:1126/180808:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[3218:3218:1126/180808:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error:Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[3218:3218:1126/180808:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

How to eliminate those errors/warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround to eliminate the warnings/errors is by installing `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

If you are using a 64-bit system, but using 32-bit software producing those warnings you might run:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Comment: To much deps The following NEW packages will be installed: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libidn11:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i

Comment: @B0nd The number of dependencies is largely irrelevant to the question. Many of these things are already installed, that shows duplicate 32-bit versions to properly support 32-bit applications.

Comment: This is what helped me solve the stupid windows 95 shapes in the menus, buttons... Even with the GTK themes properly applied, some QT programs would have these outdated shapes and they are fixed with `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` package.